# Using jquery libraries on content loaded into Fancybox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I have  form that is loaded into a FancyBox window. I would like to use a jquery InfieldLabels library on the form fields but I can't get it to work. It seems as if the script will not initialize on the Fancybox content. Here is the script I'm using to call the Fancybox:

```
$("a.bookingLink").fancybox({
'padding': 30,
'onComplete'    :   function() {
$(".inField").inFieldLabels();
}
});
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, maybe try targeting the FancyBox popup contents, then the input fields... are you sure the class names are in the loaded content?

```
$("a.bookingLink").fancybox({
  padding    : 30,
  onComplete : function() {
    $("#fancybox-content .inField").inFieldLabels();
  }
});
```

Sharing the loaded content markup would help if the above doesn't fix the problem.